# Could anybody tell me the steps to install Tomboy notes on Mac?

Tags: macos

I have been using Ubuntu since few years and have stored many notes on the Tomboy note application that comes pre-istalled with it. Now, i've migrated to Mac and finding it difficult to install Tomboy Notes app on Lion. The instruction given on Tomboy's website doesn't work for me. Could somebody please help me out?

Comment: Which part of [the instructions](http://live.gnome.org/Tomboy/Installing/Mac) isn't working? Have you installed Mono, for example?

Comment: yea..installed mono and then downloaded tomboy notes into application folder but when i click on the app it doesn't run. I have done this installation twice to no avail.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be getting much traction here. Would you link to this question in the ubuntu chat room and flag it if they indicate it would be welcome on their site. You might just find an answerer if you promote this lightly to a wider audience.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new version in beta now, but if you want the old version to work you have to install an older version of Mono, like 2.6.7 from http://download.mono-project.com/archive/2.6.7/download/.